# which submit button was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I know that which submit button was clicked on submit the form.

**HTML:**

```
<button type="submit" name="add_in_queue" id="add_in_queue" value="add_in_queue">Queue</button>
<button type="submit" name="create_tran" id="create_tran" value="create_tran">Process</button>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('form#create_tran_form').on('submit',function(e){
    var submit_value = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(submit_value);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I am getting the form ID that is: `create_tran_form`. I want to get submit button's name or value. How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to handle the `submit` event, or can you handle the `click` event for the buttons in which case `this` would refer to the clicked button?

Comment: Yes. I want to keep submit event. I can not use `click` event in this case. Because there are lots of variable those I need to pass by `serialize` method.

Comment: What should be alerted if the user hits the return key inside the form to submit it, without clicking a button?

Comment: Form is not submitting in that case.

Comment: @RonakPatel: You can still serialize the form inside a `click` handler.  I'm sure there exists valid reasons to use `submit` instead of `click`, I'm just wondering if any such reason applies here.  If the only reason is that you need to access the `form` fields, you can do that anywhere.

Comment: @RonakPatel: `"Form is not submitting in that case."` - That sounds like a very valid reason *not* to use `submit` buttons.  If you use regular buttons then pressing the return key would have no default action.  And you can just handle the click event from those buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to tell from the submit event. You need to capture the event on the button.

e.g. have an event handler that listens for submit button clicks, store the result on the form, then read it back in on your submit handler.

```
$('[type="submit"]').on('click', function (evt) {
    $(this.form).data('selected', this.value);
});

$('form').on('submit', function (evt) {
    alert($(this).data('selected'));
});
```